# Multisite and apple touch icons

Tags: 7, multi-sites

In a typical multisite D7 installation, I would like to set up apple touch icons. So that, when an agent requests `http://example-1.com/apple-touch-icon.png` then he receives the image appropriate for site **example-1**. And for site **example-2**, it should be a different image with the same name (and unfortunately at the exact same url, which is the multisite root directory). How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't totally help with the default paths, but I explicitly define them for each theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');

  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $path . '/images/favicon.png',
      'rel' => 'icon',
      'type' => 'image/png'
    ),
  ), 'MYTHEME-favicon');

  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $path . '/images/touch-icon-iphone.png',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    ),
  ), 'MYTHEME-touch-icon-iphone');

  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $path . '/images/touch-icon-ipad.png',
      'sizes' => '72x72',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    ),
  ), 'MYTHEME-touch-icon-ipad');

  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $path . '/images/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png',
      'sizes' => '114x114',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    ),
  ), 'MYTHEME-touch-icon-iphone-retina');

  drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => $path . '/images/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png',
      'sizes' => '144x144',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    ),
  ), 'MYTHEME-touch-icon-ipad-retina');
}
```